# return bounding box of transformed text element using SVG.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg.js

I am using *SVG.js* and trying to fetch the bounding box of a transformed text. I made a small example of my use case:

```
    this.draw.attr({ width: 200, height: 200 });

        const text = this.draw
            .text("some text is here")
            .attr({ x: 50, y: 50, transform: "rotate(45) scale(1.1 1.1)" });

        const textbbox = text.rbox();
        const textBorder = this.draw
            .rect(textbbox.w, textbbox.h)
            .attr({ fill: "none", "stroke-width": 1, stroke: "black" })
            .move(textbbox.x, textbbox.y);
        return this.draw;
```

Whenever I am trying to use rbox(), it returns the following error:
[image]

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: AFAIK: you can't retrieve a bounding box via `rbox()` from a not-rendered/virtual DOM element as  this method is based on `getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: That's true. Svg.js tries everything to render the element before measuring the bbox. But if it is unsuccessful it will print this error. So the solution is simply to have the shape rendered before getting the rbox/bbox